# IE Com Object, Difference between methods .Navigate and .Navigate2

Tags: internet-explorer, com, powershell, object, powershell-2.0

**What is the difference between `$ie.Navigate("URL")` and `$ie.Navigate2("URL")`**?

Get-Member says:

```
Navigate       Method    void Navigate (string, Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant)  
Navigate2      Method    void Navigate2 (Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant)
```

Sample Code:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible = $true

$ie.Navigate("www.stackoverflow.com")
#or
$ie.Navigate2("www.stackoverflow.com")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is in the first argument `URL`. Here is what MSDN says:

[Navigate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752093%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

*URL: A String expression that evaluates to the URL, full path, or Universal Naming Convention (UNC) location and name of the resource to display.*

[Navigate2 Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

*URL: A variable or expression that evaluates to the URL of the resource to display, the full path to the file location, or a PIDL that represents a folder in the Shell namespace.*

...

*This method extends the Navigate method to allow for Shell integration; however, this method does not make Navigate obsolete. The original method can still be used for URL navigations.*