# Navigate a range of URLs in random order

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have a range of cells containing URLs.
I navigate to them using a for loop like the following to get data.
I want to add some randomness.

```vb
With ie
    For j = 2 To 50
        mylink = wks.Cells(j, 2).Value
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate mylink

       'rest of code

    Next
End with
```

How can I pick a cell with a URL, navigate to it and go to the next random cell without open them again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like the following. This will generate a random number between 2 and 50, test if it has been used before (by comparing against a dictionary of used values) and then navigate. Although, I'm not entirely sure why you'd want to do this.

```
Dim UsedNumber As Object
Dim RndNumber As Long, MinNumber as long, MaxNumber as long
Dim j As Long

MinNumber = 2
MaxNumber = 50
Set UsedNumber = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With ie
    .Visible = True
    For j = MinNumber To MaxNumber
        Do
            RndNumber = Int((MaxNumber - MinNumber + 1) * Rnd + MinNumber)
        Loop While UsedNumber.exists(RndNumber)
        UsedNumber.Add RndNumber, RndNumber

        Debug.Print RndNumber

        mylink = wks.Cells(RndNumber, 2).Value

        .Navigate mylink
    Next j
End With
```

Comment: Because my guess is that the site has a mechanism that watch if I navigate to the same pages in the same order

Comment: Fair enough, if you're creating a Scraper personally I'd use Python and Scrapy for this instead of VBA

Comment: I have more questions for python :) like if can i export what i get to excel that is why i stay for now with vba

Comment: You can use Python to generate a csv file fairly easily or there are Python Modules which will create a Workbook. Either of which you could then open in Excel

Comment: Have you got any python tutorial link to share please?

Comment: Scrapy have there own tutorial you can take a look at [linky](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#)

Comment: Move the .Visible out of the loop and use .navigate2 would be useful.

Comment: @QHarr what’s the difference between .navigate and .navigate2?

Comment: I don't know whether there are more benefits but it is an extension of the existing method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538097/ie-com-object-difference-between-methode-navigate-and-navigate2   and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752094(v%3Dvs.85)