# RPC_E_DISCONNECTED during Automation of InternetExplorer

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I am trying to Automate Internet Explorer.
Occasionally, when navigating to a URL I will see the following error:  RPC_E_DISCONNECTED

```
        AutoResetEvent _isStopping = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
        try
        {
            object URL = target;
            IE.Visible = false;
            IE.Navigate2(ref URL);
            int hwnd = IE.HWND;
```

The problem happens on the Navigate2.

I did find this information which may be the problem I'm seeing, but I'm not sure how the solution translates to c#.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/08/03/default-integrity-level-and-automation/

Comment: FYI, according to the [tagging help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): _"The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use IE.Navigate instead of IE.Navigate2?

I tested it on my side and it is working fine.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie = null;
            ie = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
            ie.Navigate("www.microsoft.com", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            ie.Visible = true;
        }
```

If you want to create object using Internet Explorer medium then you can refer example below.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
                    SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium();
                    IE.Visible = true;
                    IE.Navigate("www.microsoft.com");    
        }
```

Output:

[image]

Reference:

(1) [Automate Internet Explorer using C#.Net](http://dharmesh-gadhiya82.blogspot.com/2014/05/automate-internet-explorer-using-cnet.html)

(2) [Using C# SHDocVw.InternetExplorer for form submitting](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b2b1c4a1-41b3-4682-8dbe-a28fc532acd4/using-c-shdocvwinternetexplorer-for-form-submitting?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: What's the difference between Navigate and Navigate2.  I thought Navigate2 was a newer (and improved?) method?

Comment: There are some differences in the arguments and functionality. You can refer this thread to get more information abut the difference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538097/ie-com-object-difference-between-methods-navigate-and-navigate2 I suggested it for testing purpose to verify whether using it makes any difference or not.